Attempting to get a long-stay visa while on a 90-day tourist stay in Germany
I came to Berlin a little over a month ago with the plan of moving here permanently. I got lucky and already have an apartment and was able to register my address this past week. I'm an American citizen looking to get a freelance work visa and I've been trying to get an Ausländerbehörde appointment for months leading up to being here with no luck.
My question is: if I send my documents and application using the contact form and I don't hear back by the time my 90 days is up am I allowed to continue to stay in Germany until I hear back? I understand that I would essentially be stuck in Germany until then if that were the case.
